# Dynamically set range based on column number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table with headings ID, PROFIT, COST. Those headings can be in any order. I have to define a generic approach to get the:

- count of all entries. I am currently using `=COUNTA(A2:A)`
- sum of profits. I am currently using `=SUM(B2:B)`
- average cost. I am currently using `=AVERAGE(C2:C)`

My problem is that in my current formulas I have hardcoded the columns which is a problem since they can come in any order.

I have devised a solution on how to get the correct column number. I have created a settings sheet with 1 column - all the possible column names. I then look up the correct column number by using the following formula:

```
=MATCH(Settings!B2,A1:1,False)
```

I don't know how to transfer this COLUMN NUMBER to the range of form:
(columnNumber2:columnNumber). The data is always 1 row of headers and then the data.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=INDIRECT(  ADDRESS(1, MATCH(Settings!B2, A1:1, 0), 4)&":"&
 SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, MATCH(Settings!B2, A1:1, 0), 4), 1, ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1, MATCH("ID", A1:1, 0), 4)&":"&
      SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, MATCH("ID", A1:1, 0), 4), 1, )))
```

---

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1, MATCH("PROFIT", A1:1, 0), 4)&":"&
   SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, MATCH("PROFIT", A1:1, 0), 4), 1, )))
```

---

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1, MATCH("COST", A1:1, 0), 4)&":"&
       SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, MATCH("COST", A1:1, 0), 4), 1, )))
```

Comment: Can you please explain the answer. For the first formula I get 20 when there are 19 rows of data ? When I change it to ADDRESS(2, MATCH ..... ) it works but when there is no ID column it returns 1